# to get sum of elements based on the year

Tags: javascript

input:

```
var data = [
  { team: 'A', score: 80, year: 2009 },
  { team: 'A', score: 180, year: 2009 },
  { team: 'A', score: 80, year: 2010 },
  { team: 'B', score: 80, year: 2009 },
  { team: 'B', score: 80, year: 2010 },
];
```

Output:

```
{
  2009: {
    A: 260,
    B: 80,
  },
  2010: {
    A: 80,
    B: 80,
  },
};
```

Comment: i want code in javascript for above input

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) in this way:

```js
var data = [{team: 'A', score: 80, year: 2009},{team: 'A', score: 180, year: 2009}, {team: 'A', score: 80, year: 2010}, {team: 'B', score: 80, year: 2009}, {team: 'B', score: 80, year: 2010}];

// We use reduce starting with an "accumulator" equal to an empty object.
// On every iteration of "reduce", you have access to the "accumulator" and
// the current inspected element of the array (an "object"). We also use
// "destructuring" on the current inspected object.

let res = data.reduce((acc, {year, team, score}) =>
{
    // If the value hold by property "year" is not a defined property on the
    // "acc", then set it to be an empty object.
    acc[year] = acc[year] || {};

    // If the value hold by property "team" is not a defined property on
    // "acc[year]", then set it to be 0.
    acc[year][team] = acc[year][team] || 0;

    // Increment the accumulated score on "acc[year][team]". Note this will
    // be "0", thanks to previous lines, if don't previously exists.
    acc[year][team] += score;

    // Return the altered "accumulator".
    return acc;
}, {} /* This is the initial accumulator object */);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: This is fine (code-wise), but I feel like straight-up answering such questions is just gonna encourage their askers to create more "SO is google for my programming problems" posts.

Comment: I agree with you @Jeto , I should have asked about his attempt, in first place. Sorry about this.

Comment: Hey no worries :)

Comment: @Manoj I recommend to first give a read to `Array.reduce()`. But basically you start with an `accumulator`, empty object `{}` in this case, and on every iteration of `reduce` (`reduce` traverses the array) you have access to the current inspected element, an `object` in this case, to use it and alter the `accumulator`, in case you need. In this particuar case, I use `reduce` to generate an object with the desired grouping. I will add commentaries on the code, to help a litle more.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{team: 'A', score: 80, year: 2009},{team: 'A', score: 180, year: 2009}, {team: 'A', score: 80, year: 2010}, {team: 'B', score: 80, year: 2009}, {team: 'B', score: 80, year: 2010}]
        var obj = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (obj[data[i].year]) {
                var a = obj[data[i].year]['A'];
                var b = obj[data[i].year]['B'];
                obj[data[i].year] = {
                    A: data[i].team === 'A' ? a + data[i].score : a,
                    B: data[i].team === 'B' ? b + data[i].score : b,
                }
            } else {
                obj[data[i].year] = {
                    A: data[i].team === 'A' ? data[i].score : 0,
                    B: data[i].team === 'B' ? data[i].score : 0,
                }
            }
        }
console.log(obj)
```